# using filter with foreignkey property, what is _?

Tags: python, django

my understanding is this
I have

```
class Season(models.Model):
    drama = models.ForeignKey('Drama', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

so in my views.py

```
def seasons(request, slug):
    drama = Drama.objects.get(name=drama_name)
    seasons = Season.objects.filter(drama)
```

because I have drama as foreignkey for seasons, I can use drama.name with seasons in views.py using _ underbar? but it says
'drama_name' is not defined
What am I missing?

Comment: try `drama__name` note the two `_`'s

Comment: @RedCricket I thought that was only for keyword _names_, not _values_.  i.e. `Season.objects.get(drama__name='foo')`.  Anything on the right-hand side of the equal sign is still treated as a plain variable, isn't it?

Comment: Yes your right, but I believe that is what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: What value of `name` are you searching for?  Is it something in the request, i.e. a submitted form field value?  Is it `slug`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to filter seasons by a given drama name, presumably stored in `slug`, you should simply filter the `Seasons` queryset like this (note the double underscores denoting the use of the `name` field in the foreign key `drama`):

```
def seasons(request, slug):
    seasons = Season.objects.filter(drama__name=slug)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `drama__name`. Note the two `_`'s. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships